# I want to put a validation on date picker in aura lightning component

Tags: salesforce-lightning, aura-framework

I have a date picker input in the lightning aura component.

```
<lightning:input aura:id="field"
                     type="date" 
                     name="MyDatefield" 
                     label="Enter Date" 
                     value="" 
                     min="" 
                     max="" 
                     onblur ="{!c.checkValidity }"
             />
```

And the controller is like:

```
({
    checkValidity : function(component, event, helper) {
}

})
```

I want to display the present date by default and also want to put a validation on the date that "the date should range between minimum of 5 days from the present date and maximum of 1year from the present date" otherwise display an error message.

Please help me with this because I am new to aura lightning components.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can have your logic within your onBlur event listener, or create an onChange event. Which is going to toggle the display of the alert message. You may find the syntax for an alert message on SLDS official site too.